# How to change password field to diplay asterisks instead of dots

Tags: android

I am working on the task that requires the password field (i.e.the Edit Text) to hide user input using asterisks(*) rather than dots(.). Currently it shows as dots. 
Kindly tell me the way to do it if its possible using android's native methods. Or please post the code to do it if anyone has already done that.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7):

Very late answer, and I'm sure you don't care anymore, but someone else might.

Initialize `EditText` Field .

```
 EditText UPL =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserPasswordToLogin) ;
    UPL.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Then Create a new java class ,Called `AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod.java` Which extends  **[PasswordTransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html)**

Here is code :

```
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.view.View;

public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public final void setTransformationMethod (TransformationMethod method)

Since: API Level 1
Sets the transformation that is applied to the text that this TextView is displaying.
Related XML Attributes

android:password
android:singleLine
```

allows you to change any char

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you could override the listener class methods to modify the text to display so that it reads as "*****", but keep the actual string in the background somewhere.  So each time the user enters a letter, you add it to your cumulative "password" string, and instead, replace that character in the displayed string with *