# How I can change the icon on an EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I make EditText to receive a password from the user.

So I changed the input type to password.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_Password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
```

When I put word in EditText, it shows a black dot.
I want change the dot to a drawable resource.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125352/how-to-change-password-field-to-diplay-asterisks-instead-of-dots?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I don't think you can set drawable instead of a char.

Comment: Can you post required UI.

Comment: @Khemraj Just circle like that

Comment: @ManishGupta Yes I see it but it returns char. I want drawable resource

Comment: @PolarisNation do you want to change color of dot?

Comment: @PolarisNation check this https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write code for your requirement following this code.

The answer comes from [this tutorial](http://nikshits.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/edittext-with-star-image-for-password/) and it covers a behaviour when a user:

- enters into the login screen, keyboard will open automatically.
- tries to enter value in it then textbox background changes to textbox with star background.
- tries to cancel/delete the input value by using back key on keyboard then textbox background will change to textbox without star background.

First of all you have to create two `drawables`:

[image]

[image]

Then, according to this approach, you have to implement `addTextChangedListener` method on your `EditText`. After that, as a parameter, you create a new instance of a `TextWatcher` class and you implement its methods:

```
etxtPin1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          if(etxtPin1.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){

          etxtPin1.clearFocus();
          etxtPin2.requestFocus();
          etxtPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pin_txt_bg_star);

          }
       }
    });
```

Then, you have to implement `setOnKeyListener` and its method `onKey`:

```
this.etxtPin1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
      public boolean onKey(View paramView, int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
           if ((paramKeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(paramInt == 67) && (LoginActivity.this.etxtPin2.getText().length() == 0)) {
               etxtPin1.requestFocus();
               etxtPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pin_txt_bg);
               etxtPin1.setText("");
           }

           return false;
       }
    });
```

[image]

---

**Another approach:** create you own class which extends [PasswordTransformationMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.java).

```
public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Reference: [In android how to show asterisk (*) in place of dots in EditText having inputtype as textPassword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597648/in-android-how-to-show-asterisk-in-place-of-dots-in-edittext-having-inputtyp/11597660#11597660)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849287/6891563)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. But in another approach, is it returns char? not drawable resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the dots in edit text, then you can change the text color which will change the color of dots also.

You can use this code to do the same:

```
android:textColor="#FF0000" or setTextColor(int)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the answer I wanted